# Python, NetworkX hexagonal lattice problem - how to create a perfect lattice?

Tags: python, networkx, physics, lattice

So I am trying to generate a hexagonal lattice using NetworkX in Python. After using code:

```
G = nx.hexagonal_lattice_graph(m=2, n=2, periodic=False, with_positions=True, create_using=None)
plt.subplot(111)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

I am getting a hexagonal lattice which looks like this:
[lattice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYTBS.png)

As you can see, this lattice is formed from irregular hexagons and everytime the code is ran the shape changes. Is there a way to generate a perfect hexagonal lattice using NetworkX, i.e [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUSTs.png), but with only X number of hexagons?

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend embedding the images into the question.

Comment: The answer is yes and you need to use `pos` parameter in `nx.draw()` which defines exact position of your vertices.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `with_postion` attribute in the `hexagonal_lattic_graph` function and set it to `True`. This will store the positions of the nodes in an attribute called `pos` inside the Graph `G` itself. You can read more about from the documentation [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.lattice.hexagonal_lattice_graph.html):

> **with_positions (bool (default: True))** – Store the coordinates of each node in the graph node attribute ‘pos’. The coordinates provide a lattice with vertical columns of hexagons offset to interleave and cover the plane. Periodic positions shift the nodes vertically in a nonlinear way so the edges don’t overlap so much.

So, you just need to extract the positions from the graph itself, like this:

```
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')
```

Then, pass this with `pos` while drawing your graph

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create the graph and set with_positions=True
G = nx.hexagonal_lattice_graph(m=2, n=2, periodic=False, with_positions=True, create_using=None)
plt.subplot(111)

# Extract the positions
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')

# Pass the positions while drawing
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image: Hexagonal lattices]