# Weighted hexagonal lattice using networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I would like to create a network made of hexagonal geometry similar to the following link:

[Python, NetworkX hexagonal lattice problem - how to create a perfect lattice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63457355/python-networkx-hexagonal-lattice-problem-how-to-create-a-perfect-lattice)

What I would like to do is to change the weight of each edge from default 1.0 to anything I like but constant for the whole network. Also, when I plot it using the networkx.draw, I want to reflect that weight on the length of the hexagonal lattice. I searched lot and found some examples when they use the G.add_edge(1,2, length = 10) where you know each node information specifically. But my network can be any size. Is there any easy way doing it? Thank you so much.

Comment: If all weights are the same, do you only care about the (scaling of the) drawing?

Comment: @Sparky05 Hello, Kind of yes